# Converting matter into plasma using Sunlight?

Tags: thermodynamics, photons, states-of-matter

How much light is needed to convert elements from a lower-state-of-matter such as from a solid directly to plasma without a liquid state, if that is possible?. Which element would produce the most reaction or matter-change, no matter the state, per photon? Is there a list of some type?

Comment: You may find most of your questions answered at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_ablation

Comment: @KFGauss That does help, but I am hoping for something along the line of sunlight

Comment: I updated the title